# Problems with dash movemement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem, im trying to create a dash move but currently it aims at nothing and it goes bckwards if im facing to de right or up, and im trying to make it go towards the front on the player.

[The Code Im Using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdvP4.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) but provide it as text

Comment: Are you **sure** you are using the old C# 3 (2007) with Unity?

Answer (score 0):

Some general things: I'd recommend using a Time.deltaTime or the variant for fixedupdate in your cooldown timer. Also, fixedupdate is for physics, but it's best to monitor the input in the regular update function.

regarding your issue: I think it has something to do with line 32. The way you calculate your dashpoint is rather unusual. What is this line supposed to do exactly?